# Three.JS gltf model disappearing when using left click orbit control

Tags: javascript, three.js

Well, the title pretty much says it all.
I am using [camera-controls](https://cdn.skypack.dev/camera-controls) for OrbitControls (because the official one doesn't seem to work anymore), and recently popped into that problem :

Whenever I press left click and drag my mouse, the model simply disappears and can never be found again. Zooming works perfectly and can't seem to find any potential solution for that matter.

Hope you can help! Here is the code. Thank you in advance!

```js
import cameraControls from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/camera-controls';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

cameraControls.install( { THREE: THREE } )

let obj, controls;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( window.innerWidth / - 2, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2, window.innerHeight / - 2, 0.01, 1000 );


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

camera.position.z = 50;

const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load("../models/EGLISE.glb", function(gltf) {
    obj = gltf.scene
    scene.add(obj);
    gltf.animations;
}, undefined, function(error){
    console.error(error);
});

controls = new cameraControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

controls.minZoom = 1;
controls.maxZoom = 5;

const ambientlight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff );
scene.add( ambientlight );

const light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xff0000, 1, 100 );
light.position.set( 50, 50, 50 );
scene.add( light );

const animate = function () {

    if(obj){
        obj.rotation.y += 0.001;
        // document.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
        //  obj.rotation.y += 0.01;
        // })
    controls.update();
    }

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

};

if ( WEBGL.isWebGLAvailable() ) {

    animate();

} else {

    const warning = WEBGL.getWebGLErrorMessage();
    document.getElementById( 'container' ).appendChild( warning );

}
```

Comment: This usually happens when the camera position receives an invalid value, like `NaN`. What happens when you output its position with `console.log(camera.position.toArray())` after it's disappeared?

Comment: Does the same thing happen with a simple cube? It could be a problem with your GLB.